# negative or null values in custom function

Tags: r, lidr

I'm working with the package `lidR` (v 4.0.3) to extract the tree positions using a custom function but it behaves weirdly. If I use the following, I get an error:

```r
f = function(x) { 0.413 * x^0.5532 }
ttops = locate_trees(r, lmf(f, hmin=2, shape = "circular")) # raster based search
    
#> Error in if (any(ws <= 0)) stop("The function 'ws' returned negative or null values.",  : 
#>      missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

while if I use this, it works:

```r
f = function(x) { x * 0.08 + 1.5 }
```

If the parameter `hmin` filters pixels above 2 metres, how is it possible that I get a negative or null value?

Going a bit deeper, I saw that data contains both `NA`s and `NaN`s; nevertheless, if I apply the functions to a vector with the raster values, the results are correct.

```r
ss = terra::values(r)
ss = ss[ss >= 2]
ws = 0.413 * ss^0.5532
any(!is.na(ws) & ws<0)
#> [1] FALSE
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an internal test in `lmf()` that checks if the user function does not return windows sizes `<= 0`. This test is performed for every single point and is not aware of the parameter `hmin`. So in theory you are correct, your function `f` looks ok. In practice you must ensure that your function **never** return values `<= 0`

```r
f = function(x) { 
  x[x < 5] = 5
  0.413 * x^0.5532 
}

plot(f(-2:40))
```

I also recommend to protect your function against outliers

```r
f = function(x) { 
  x[x < 5] = 5
  x[x > 30] = 30
  0.413 * x^0.5532 
}

plot(f(-2:40))
```

Comment: Thanks! such suggestion could be integrated into the example in the lmf function help page or in the lidRbook